# Какого рода "Динамо"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какого рода будет слово "Динамо" в названии футбольной команды. В смысле, как сказать: "Динамо" победило" или "Динамо" победила"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Динамо" - победило. 
Правило о родовом слове обычно применимо для слов иноязычных, несклоняемых и/или недостаточно освоенных русским язывком. В тех же случаях, когда род определяется, пардон, по "первичныным грамматическим признакам", такого не требуется.
Динамо - название, которое давно на слуху. Ко всему прочему не всегда ясно, идет ли речь о команде или клубе. Так что - не заморачивайтесь, язык сам подскажет.
Едиственная сложность - ЦСКА (СКА), он мужского рода.
Ну еще всякие сокращения и иноязычные названия (УГМ, АЕК, АПОЕЛ, ВИЗ-СИНАРА и т.д.) там действительно лучше подстелить соломки, хотя по факту все такие названия обычно мужского рода.

Comment: Ваше "ппрдон" - совсем непонятно!

Comment: Почему непонятно? Пардон.  
Извинение за ассоциации, которые может вызвать последующее словосочетание.

Comment: >Ваше "ппрдон" - совсем непонятно!  
Спасибо, исправлюсь.

Comment: Так Вы все-таки кот? )))))

Comment: Разве Бегемот не может быть котом?
В прошлой жизни я был Чеширским Бегемотом.
Потом у меня невесть откуда появились "родственники".

Answer (score 2):

**Д.Э. Розенталь:**
При подлежащем - условном названии применяется принцип грамматического согласования, например: ***"Известия" увеличили свой тираж; "Воскресение" Было впервые опубликовано Л.Н. Толстым в журнале "Нива"***.
**Если условное название - несклоняемое слово, то сказуемое согласуется с ним или как с субстантивированным словом (т.е. ставится в форме среднего рода), или по смыслу (т.е. согласуется с родовым наименованием по отношению к данному слову)**. Например: 1) ***"Накануне" помещено в третьем томе собрания сочинений И.С.Тургенева; 2) "Вперёд" (линкор) вышел в открытое море.*** Второй принцип согласования обычно применяется при иноязычных несклоняемых наименованиях промышленных компаний, спортивных организаций и т.п., например: ..."Тре крунур" (спортивная команда) проиграла нашим хоккеистам оба матча.

Получается, что сказуемое при ***несклоняемом*** существительном "Динамо" можно употребить и в среднем роде, и в женском.

Comment: А если "Динамо" - это, например, клуб, то и в мужском роде можно употребить.

Comment: Тут все-таки есть один момент. "Динамо" - ну никак не иноязычное наименование.   

В разговор вмешалась мама:   
- Эти ноги у "Динамо".   
Очень жаль, что наш " Спартак"   
Не догонит их никак!

Comment: "Динамо" — не только клуб, но и команда. Значит, с тем же успехом можно сказать "победила"))

Comment: Побездают как правило именно команды. Но это нименно "как правило", могут быть и соревнования клуб на клуб: по несколько команд от каждого клуба, разных возрастов например.

Answer (score 1):

"Динамо" - это приложение к определяемому слову "команда". По правилам, глаголы согласуются  в таком случае с определяемым словом, значит, "Динамо" победила". Правда, такая фраза не очень хорошо звучит. Я бы сказал: "Команда "Динамо" победила". Однако здесь наблюдаются процессы смещения акцента на приложение: Газета "Коммерсант" поместила статью", но "Комменрсант" поместил статью".

Answer (score -2):

При чём тут команда или клуб? "Динамо" в переводе с латыни - "сила". Другое значение этого слова - "машина" или "генератор". Поэтому название "Динамо" никак не может иметь средний род.

Comment: Это ответ. Нечетко сформклированный, но все-таки ответ. Удалять не вижу смысла, автор выразил свою мысль по сути вопроса. Славик, постарайтесь  в дальнейшем формулировать так, чтобы ни у кого не было сомнения, что вы именно утверждаете про грамматический род слова,  а не спрашиваете всех "при чем тут..."

Comment: Что касается самого вашего ответа, то он мне представляется неверным по той причине, что именно родовое слово "команда" или "клуб" может опредялять род слова ("Динамо" - общество), но не в данном случае. См. мой ответ.